# Rsync not correctly mirroring content

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I am trying to sync content between two servers. The servers are identical builds (Ubuntu 12.04LTS) and have this cron job running to sync the content:

`rsync -arzc --update --delete /htdocs/testing/www/cms_uploads/* root@123.123.123.123:/htdocs/testing/www/cms_uploads/`

but I'm getting some strange results when I am testing the process as detailed below.

**First test**

- Uploaded aaaa.jpg to Node2
- syncs to Node1
- Delete from Node1
- Reappears on Node1
- Delete from Node2
- Removed from Node1

**Second test**

- Uploaded bbbb.png to Node1
- Syncs to Node2
- Delete from Node2
- Reappears on Node2
- Delete from Node 1
- Reappears on Node1

All I am trying to do is make sure the same content is exactly the same on both servers all the time. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

rsync is one way only! try Unison if you need bidirectional syncronisation or shared storage

dont use wildcards. 
Be careful with ending slashes (once set the wrong time and you can loose your files!)